# Trying to render App & getting -> Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, react-testing-library, redux-toolkit

I am creating vite + typescript + redux app and I have a problem with testing my App component to render, using vitest for testing. I use redux@toolkit and get a problem, when trying to use async thunk in the app component:

```
Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
 ❯ dispatch node_modules/redux-mock-store/lib/index.js:41:19
 ❯ getAirports src/App.tsx:19:17
     17|       if (airportsStatus === "idle") {
     18|         const getAirports = async () => {
     19|           await dispatch(fetchAirports());
       |                 ^
     20|         };
     21|
```

**Here is how my test file is configured:**

```
import App from "../App";
import { it } from "vitest";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import configureStore from "redux-mock-store";
import {
  ThunkDispatch,
  UnknownAction,
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { RootState } from "../common/types";
import { store } from "../app/store";
import thunk from "redux-thunk"

const mockStore = configureStore<
    RootState,
    ThunkDispatch<RootState, undefined, UnknownAction>
  >();

it("should have hello world", async () => {
  const initialState: RootState = {
    airports: {
      airports: [{
        id: 100,
        code: "TBS",
        title: "Tbilisi International Airport"
      }],
      status: "idle",
      error: null,
    },
    bookings: {
      bookings: [{
      firstName: "Alexis",
      lastName: "Doe",
      departureAirportId: 100,
      arrivalAirportId: 101,
      departureDate: "2024-12-29T00:00:00.000Z",
      returnDate: "2024-12-30T00:00:00.000Z"
    }],
      status: "idle",
      error: null,
    },
  };

  const store = mockStore(initialState);

  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  );

  // expect(getByText("Hello World!")).not.toBeNull();
});
```

**And here is my App component:**

```
const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const effectRan = useRef(false);
  const airportsStatus = useAppSelector(getAirportsStatus);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (effectRan.current === false) {
      if (airportsStatus === "idle") {
        const getAirports = async () => {
          await dispatch(fetchAirports());
        };

        getAirports();

        // sync () => {
        //   await dispatch(fetchAirports());
        //   })()
      }

      return () => {
        effectRan.current = true;
      };
    }
  }, [dispatch, airportsStatus]);
  
  return (
    <>
      <Form />
      <ListWithBookings />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Here is how my redux store is configured:**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import airportsReducer from "../features/airports/airportsSlice";
import bookingsReducer from "../features/bookings/bookingsSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    airports: airportsReducer,
    bookings: bookingsReducer,
  }
});
```

This problem is bothering me all day and I just can't solve it. Thank you!

I tried many things, but right now it doesn't give me any error about types or something, the simple problem is this fetch.

Comment: Can you share me the code for `fetchAirports`?

Comment: Hey, Jason! The solution of Drew solved the problem, so there is no need to bother you with it! Thank you so much anyway! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "mock store" isn't configured to handle asynchronous actions, e.g. it's not using the Thunk middleware. See [`redux-mock-store` Asynchronous Actions](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-mock-store?tab=readme-ov-file#asynchronous-actions).

```js
import configureStore from "redux-mock-store";
import thunk from "redux-thunk"

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);
```

```js
import App from "../App";
import { it } from "vitest";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import configureStore from "redux-mock-store";
import {
  ThunkDispatch,
  UnknownAction,
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { RootState } from "../common/types";
import { store } from "../app/store";
import thunk from "redux-thunk"

const middlewares = [thunk];

const mockStore = configureStore<
  RootState,
  ThunkDispatch<RootState, undefined, UnknownAction>
>(middlewares);

it("should have hello world", async () => {
  const initialState: RootState = {
    airports: {
      airports: [{
        id: 100,
        code: "TBS",
        title: "Tbilisi International Airport"
      }],
      status: "idle",
      error: null,
    },
    bookings: {
      bookings: [{
      firstName: "Alexis",
      lastName: "Doe",
      departureAirportId: 100,
      arrivalAirportId: 101,
      departureDate: "2024-12-29T00:00:00.000Z",
      returnDate: "2024-12-30T00:00:00.000Z"
    }],
      status: "idle",
      error: null,
    },
  };

  const store = mockStore(initialState);

  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  );

  // expect(getByText("Hello World!")).not.toBeNull();
});
```

Be aware that mocking a Redux store is no longer the recommended method. See [Writing Tests](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests) for details. You should instantiate an actual legitimate store, the same way your app does.

```js
import App from "../App";
import { it } from "vitest";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import airportsReducer from "../features/airports/airportsSlice";
import bookingsReducer from "../features/bookings/bookingsSlice";
import { RootState } from "../common/types";

const reducer = {
  airports: airportsReducer,
  bookings: bookingsReducer,
};

const preloadedState: RootState = {
  airports: {
    airports: [{
      id: 100,
      code: "TBS",
      title: "Tbilisi International Airport"
    }],
    status: "idle",
    error: null,
  },
  bookings: {
    bookings: [{
    firstName: "Alexis",
    lastName: "Doe",
    departureAirportId: 100,
    arrivalAirportId: 101,
    departureDate: "2024-12-29T00:00:00.000Z",
    returnDate: "2024-12-30T00:00:00.000Z"
  }],
    status: "idle",
    error: null,
  },
};

it("should have hello world", async () => {
  const store = configureStore({
    preloadedState,
    reducer,
  });

  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  );

  // expect(getByText("Hello World!")).not.toBeNull();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Drew, it solved it! I tried with just passing the initial store previously, but it is not the right approach, right? Just to be clear, that I understand it correctly - when I want to load the store, I don't need to mock it, but just create like copy of my legitimate store?

Comment: @IliaPopov Correct, create a real Redux store.